# drop several multilevel from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Giving the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                              'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                              'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                       'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                       'D' : np.random.randn(8)})

def var1(x): return max(x)-min(x)
def var2(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/max(x)
def var3(x): return (max(x)-min(x))/ len(x)

df = df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C': var1, 'D': [var2, var3]})

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

[image: output]

But `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()` is not the solution I want because I can only drop one level. I would like to drop those 2 first levels.

## Edit

I already tried `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()` with: `0,1,2..`

I wanna get a df without the red cells:

[image]

In other words i cant reach to this output(one simple header):

```
A   B       var1        var2        var3        
bar one     0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000
    three   0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000
    two     0.000000    -0.000000   0.000000
foo one     1.381629    -1.683335   0.582389
    three   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
    two     0.636372    -0.031118   0.020791
```

Comment: And `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)` ?

Comment: Or, `df.columns = df.columns.levels[1]`?

Comment: I cant get what I want, you have to notice that I would still having "2 levels", and the output is not what I "printed" in the target solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df = df.rename_axis([None] * 2)
#or
#df.index.names = [None] * 2
print (df)
               var2      var3      var1
bar one   -0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    three -0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    two   -0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
foo one   -8.719019  0.461249  1.596351
    three  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    two    2.415974  0.558326  2.888277
```

But is possible add columns names, but here is only one level of columns, so only scalar is possible:

```
df.columns.name = 'AB'
print (df)
AB             var2      var3      var1
bar one   -0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    three -0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    two    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
foo one    0.469283  0.431255  0.164785
    three -0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    two    0.967594  0.715657  0.827949
```

Comment: have you tried your suggestion? it was in my own question, it wasnt working to get what i asked for..

Comment: Hmmm, it is only display thing. But is not possible have index names `A, B` without blank space, because pandas devs code this blank space :(

Comment: there is no way to convert it into a regular dataframe?

Comment: But it is normal nice dataframe ;) Nothing bad. This space is only for better distinguish what is columns and what is index. Dont worry ;)